# Static Bundle Identifier

Tags: ios, bundle

How can I have only one Bundle Identifier  for all apps? Now Then I change app name Bundle Identifier changes too. Problem is that I have app name on language of my country, but Bundle Identifier  must be only english

Answer (score 0):

A bundle identifier can only be used for one app; not for multiple apps. Are you using localization data for your apps? That would be the best way to handle the different languages.

Answer (score 0):

So first off, you really should not release separate apps for localization alone. App Store guidelines prohibit this, though enforcement has been lax.

Second off, a bundle identifier is a UTI. 
UTIs are basically reverse URL format strings. 
That means you can apply similar conventions and have sub domains in your bundle identifiers. 
The correct approach would be to create multiple bundle identifiers that all have common domains and some difference in the lowest sub domain.

com.mycompany.myapp.somethingelsedisyinguoshingvariantsofmyapp

That makes it easy to identify your apps as yours. 
And all of them as some app, but as variants.